# Image cannot be sent to my server

Tags: python, ios, swift, django, xcode

Image cannot be sent to my server.
Uploading image to a server cannot be done. I am making Swift app and I wanna make a system in my app which uploading a image to my Django server. Now,PhotoController(it is for the system)is

```
import Foundation
import MobileCoreServices
import UIKit
class PhotoController:UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var myActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    private var imagePicker:UIImagePickerController!

    @IBAction func uploadButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        myImageUploadRequest()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        label.text = "Tap the PhotoSelect or Camera to upload a picture"
     }

    @IBAction func PhotoSelect(_ sender: Any) {
        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = self;
        myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

        self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func Camera(_ sender: Any) {
        let sourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        // カメラが利用可能かチェック
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
            // インスタンスの作成
            let cameraPicker = UIImagePickerController()
            cameraPicker.sourceType = sourceType
            cameraPicker.delegate = self
            self.present(cameraPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        else{
            label.text = "error"   
        }
    } 
    //　撮影が完了時した時に呼ばれる
    func imagePickerController(_ imagePicker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            myImageView.image = pickedImage

        }

        //閉じる処理
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        label.text = "Tap the Send to save a picture"

    }

    // 撮影がキャンセルされた時に呼ばれる
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        label.text = "Canceled"
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func myImageUploadRequest()
    {

        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8000/admin/accounts/post/");
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL);
        request.httpMethod = "POST";
        //ユーザーごとに割り振りたい
        let param = [
            "firstName"  : "Sergey",
            "lastName"    : "Kargopolov",
            "userId"    : "9"
        ]

        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image!, 1)

        if(imageData==nil)  { return; }

        request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: param, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData! as NSData, boundary: boundary) as Data


        myActivityIndicator.startAnimating();

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            print("******* response = \(response)")

            // Print out reponse body
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self.myImageView.image = nil;
                }

            }catch
            {
                print(error)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }
    func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
        let body = NSMutableData();

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }

        let filename = "user-profile.jpg"
        let mimetype = "image/jpg"

        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(imageDataKey as Data)
        body.appendString(string: "\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")

        return body
    }

    func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
        return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
    }

}
extension NSMutableData {

    func appendString(string: String) {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        append(data!)
    }
}
```

This url  let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8000/admin/accounts/post/"); is my server's image upload url. Traceback is

```
2017-06-14 23:04:50.480209 Kenshin_Swift[262:8094] [Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error
2017-06-14 23:04:52.660264 Kenshin_Swift[262:8267] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
error=Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x174456e90 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:8000/admin/accounts/post/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:8000/admin/accounts/post/, NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.})
```

My Info.plist is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
   <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
   <dict>
    <key>example.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
   </dict>
  </dict>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>for photo library</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>for camera</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Traceback told me my Info.plist is wrong but I do not know what is wrong.
Surely,I added

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>example.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

to Info.plist,so I cannot understand why image cannot be sent to my server.I thought this was Info.plist error, but this error is in my server,right?How can I fix this?

Comment: can you post the some snippet of your server (django) code since it is a django code's problem

Answer (score 0):

In your info.plist

replace this

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>example.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

to this

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you need to use https protocol in case you connect to host over domain name(Apple requirement). If you could not implement https, you can connect over http but you must use IP-address.